How to set a Google Sheets' Cell Note based off a Cell Value that begins with a Plus Sign
In a Google Apps script for the Google Sheet, I have this code with an OnEdit Trigger. It updates a cell's Note based off the value I pick from a drop down list, which was created for the cell using a "Data Validation" (Dropdown from Range).
The values from a separate that the dropdown contain, some have a + in front of them
eg.  +1 to modifier
I have tried formatting the values for the dropdown range
eg.  ="+1 to modifier
Theerafter the dropdown chosen value itself does not cause an error when modified as above.
But then the following Apps Script, used to set the chosen dropdown value as a note, breaks and the note is not added, shows error:
function addNotescToRange() {
// Get the "GraveLayout" sheet
const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GraveLayout");

// Define the range (A1:B2) (to set Notes for each cell based off its value)
const range1 = sheet1.getRange("A1:B2");

// Get the values in the range as a two-dimensional array
const values = range1.getValues();

// Loop through each cell in the range
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      const cell = range1.getCell(i + 1, j + 1); // +1 for zero-based indexing
      const value = values[i][j];

      // Set the note for the cell using its value
      cell.setNote(value);
    }

}
}

I added the apostrophe manually to append it to the value in this final part of the code but the note still errors:
// Set the note for the cell using its value 
cell.setNote('"' & value);


Could you please explain why there are backslashes in the code? \< values\[i\].length

I apologise, I'm not certain how it formatted it in there, let me update it as follows :
// Loop through each cell in the range   for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {     for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {       const cell = range1.getCell(i + 1, j + 1); // +1 for zero-based indexing       const value = values[i][j];

Here is an editor enabled Public sheet to see the script work in cell A2 but fail when the plus sign value is being added as a note. Hover on cell to see the Note for the cell.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qJTph-wLBfROttqdaQhGt7aFeAu8VHuK-Ve9LA3wTxc/edit?usp=sharing

In GAS, concatenation uses not &, but +. That is, if you want to add an apostrophe before the value, then the code should not be cell.setNote(' " ' & value), but cell.setNote(" ' " + value).
But this will not help you, since the problem arises because you use ="+1 to modifier" in the value range for the dropdown menu.
If this particular spelling (as a formula) is not important to you, then use the spelling '+1 to modifier (as text).
In this case, the value is understood correctly, no error occurs, and the note is set correctly.
I corrected the values in the range E4:E5 in your spreadsheet and now everything works fine.

The concatenation was not the issue I see now. But the type of apostrophe in the value. Thank you very much!
